# nlog .netcore turn off microsoft INFO level logging

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, nlog

How can I turn off Microsoft info level logging in nlog / .netcore ?

I still want info logging for my other loggers

I currently have:

```
  <rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="nxlog_json" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="human_text_file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="nxlog_json" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="human_text_file" />
  </rules>
```

This does not work, If i remove:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="nxlog_json" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="human_text_file" />
```

It does work for the microsoft logging , but then removes all logging for the other loggers.

What am i missing ? I am assuming the logger name="*" overrides the first entrys for Microsoft.*, but I don't want to have to explicitly specify my other loggers names.

Answer (score 12):

Use `final=true` that stops other filters processing if current filter applyed. And write `"blackHole"` target to swallow messages:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackHole" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="blackHole" final="true" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="nxlog_json" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="human_text_file" />
</rules>
```

NLog 4.5 allows one to specify an empty writeTo=""

```
<rules>
  <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="" final="true" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="nxlog_json" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="human_text_file" />
</rules>
```

Official wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#routing

Comment: You can omit `writeTo`, from [docs](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file): '...but since there is no **writeTo**, these messages are not logged. And, since this rule contains 'final=true', the last rule does not apply to loggers matching the first rule.'

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically use something along the lines of:

```cs
LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(builder =>
{
   // turn off microsoft logging, unless warnings
   c.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);

   var consoleTarget = c.ForTarget("console").WriteTo(new ConsoleTarget()).WithAsync();
   c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Debug).WriteTo(consoleTarget);
});
```

See also: https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#fluent-api-for-nlog-loggingconfiguration